# How should I communicate between layers and optimize my code?

Tags: c#, n-tier-architecture

I'm building a REST Web API on C#. My code is divide in 4 layers:

> - Model
> - Repository
> - Service
> - Web API

How can I connect Service and Repository model efficient, without repeat a lote of code? Right now one of my Service Layer class looks like this:

```
public class ContactosService : IContactosService
{
    public string EmpresaId { get; set; }

    public void AddContact(Contact_mdl value)
    {
        using (var myCon = new AdoNetContext(new AppConfigConnectionFactory(EmpresaId)))
        {
            using (var rep = new Contact_rep(myCon))
            {
                rep.Add(value);
            }
        }
    }

    public void DeleteContact(int id)
    {
        using (var myCon = new AdoNetContext(new AppConfigConnectionFactory(EmpresaId)))
        {
            using (var rep = new Contact_rep(myCon))
            {
                rep.Delete(id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This looks to me to be very inneficient, and I find myself writting lots of almost identical classes? Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Writing a lot of _almost_ identical classes is a very misunderstood style. Classes should be used for designing your application, not just for code reuse IMHO

Comment: So, you suggest me to let it like it is?

Comment: I think your question is too broad to have a single answer here, You can check many architectures like CQRS and ..., and we always using some base classes in an infrastructure layer or in a core part of a layer to implement some Generic and abstract classes to avoid duplicated codes -HTH ;).

Comment: I'm saying that code reuse should not be your first concern when you design your layers. If there is functionality you can reuse you can put it in an external library, but remember that _code reuse is not functionality reuse_
Yes, it is possible that having a lot of almost identical classes to be the best idea for the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple or short/quick answer to your question. Also, a lot of variables comes into play when designing systems architecture. I would just give a few generic advices:

- Make your decisions as late as possible, the more knowledge you have before making decision the better
- Prototype, try out concepts in a smaller scale

For you particular code sample, it would be common practise to isolate code in a single place (service) while injecting action and using it as a command to follow DRY. Also, it avoids inconstencies while refactoring.

Consider example:

```
public class ContactosService : IContactosService
{
    private readonly IContactRepository repository;

    public ContactosService(IContactRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void AddContact(Contact_mdl value)
    {
        repository.Execute(rep => rep.Add(value));
    }

    public void DeleteContact(int id)
    {
        repository.Execute(rep => rep.Delete(id));
    }
}

public class ContactRepository : IContactRepository
{
    private readonly string _empresaId;
    public ContactRepository(string empresaId)
    {
         _empresaId = empresaId;
    }

    public void Execute(Action<Contact_rep> command)
    {
        using (var myCon = new AdoNetContext(new AppConfigConnectionFactory(_empresaId)))
        {
            using (var rep = new Contact_rep(myCon))
            {
                command(rep);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all your effort. I see where you going, but I don't exactly understand your code. Are you suggesting to expand ContactRepository con repository layer on ServiceLayer? Or should all my repositorys implement an Execute method?

Comment: @ericpap It depends whether your other repositories use same method stub. If you do then you can reuse it through out your repositories. In general you want to combine and reuse code. If it could be used for other repositories, then go ahead with use it for all of them. If not, try to find common code and extract it into a single place which could be reused. That is whole idea behind it.